# Force refresh on back button press with Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, back

I'm using PhoneGap with Android, and I need my app to force a refresh when the Android back button takes the app back to a certain page. Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can override 'onBackPressed' method.

show below example codes.

```
package com.test.phonegap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.phonegap.DroidGap;

public class TestPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {

    String Index_html = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl(Index_html);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //this.loadUrl(Index_html);
        this.loadUrl("javascript:method_name()");
    }
}
```

---

- Changes

if you wanna control page navigation when back key pressed,
call javascript function in 'onBackPressed' method.

Above code will call function javasctipt named 'method_name' when back pressed.
and you can write 'page-control code' in javascript function.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I need the refresh to not be page specific though. So for instance, if my hierarchy is 3 levels deep, I don't want pressing the back button on level 3 to take me to level 1 instead of level 2. I'm guessing there might be a Javascript solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a new activity using the `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` method.  If the back button is pressed within that new activity, it will send a cancelled result to the previous activity, which in turn must handle that result.  Therefore, in the first activity, catch that result using:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELLED) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

From here, all you need do is create a method that implements the refresh that you desire, and call it from within the above code.

Comment: I think he means while browsing the web, so the user is not switching activities but rather the back button is navigating back a page